# Use BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS (or similar) with semicolon as separator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

**The goal :**

I want to declare the following collection of classes (simplified example) with preprocessing technique :

```
template <typename A>
class MyClassName_0
{
  private:
};
template <typename A, typename X0>
class MyClassName_1
{
  private:
    X0 const& x0;
};
template <typename A, typename X0, typename X1>
class MyClassName_2
{
  private:
    X0 const& x0;
    X1 const& x1;
};
/* ... */
template <typename A, typename X0, typename X1, /* ... */ typename X99>
class MyClassName_100
{
  private:
    X0 const& x0;
    X1 const& x1;
    /* ... */
    X99 const& x99;
};
```

**What I did :**

I defined a template class by this way :

```
#define MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_DECLARATION(z, n, data) \
  template <typename A BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n) BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, typename X)> \
  class MyClassName_ ## n \
  { \
  };
```

Then I can enumerate the classes :

```
#define MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_DECLARATIONS(n) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_PP_INC(n), MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_DECLARATION, 0)
MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_DECLARATIONS(100)
```

**My question :**

I don't see how to write the private members **with boost**. Is there a magical function similar to `BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS` but with a semicolon as separator ?

**My solution :**

I know I can write this macro by myself. It's quite simple actually :

```
#define MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_PRIVATE_DECLARATION(z, n, data) \
  X ## n const& x ## n;
#define MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_PRIVATE_DECLARATIONS(n) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_PRIVATE_DECLARATION, 0)
```

and then call it by :

```
#define MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_DECLARATION(z, n, data) \
  template <typename A BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n) BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, typename X)> \
  class MyClassName_ ## n \
  { \
    private: \
      MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_PRIVATE_DECLARATIONS(n)
  };
```

but I'm wondering if I can only do something similar to :

```
#define MAKE_MYCLASSNAME_DECLARATION(z, n, data) \
  template <typename A BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n) BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, typename X)> \
  class MyClassName_ ## n \
  { \
    private: \
      BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS(n, X, const& x)
  };
```

Comment: Is your problem that you want `X` and `const& x` to be a customizable part of the macro interface or do you just want an "official" Boost.Preprocessor way?

Comment: @jv_ : I just want an official boost.pp way to do that, if it exists.

Comment: I don't think there is one, but I'm not an expert. Hope you find a satisfying solution.